# JsonSerializationException 'Unable to find a constructor' on Xamarin.Android with .NET Standard Library

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, json.net

I have used Xamarin Native UI for Android application and Created different class library for API call and data Deserialize api data using `Newtonsoft.Json`.

That class library Target Framework is `.NET Standar 2.0`.

As I have added that reference to the console application so its working fine but same reference i have add in Android project its throw error.

`**Error Details**` 
`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute.`

As per error message i have used attribute `JsonConstructor` for default constructor of class.

Example:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public TestClass()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the Mono Linker setting for the build configuration that you are getting the error with.

Comment: @SushiHangover Sdk and User Assemblies.

Comment: Use the `PreserveAttribute` in Arvinfraja's answer

Comment: @SushiHangover , As `PreserveAttribute` required `Mono.Android.dll` Or 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' reference in that but my class library is Common for both thats why it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As PreserveAttribute required Mono.Android.dll Or 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' reference in that but my class library is Common for both thats why it is not possible

Add a `PreserveAttribute` class to your class library and use that attribute as the Mono Linker only uses the "name" of the attribute and not the namespace/classname...

```
public sealed class PreserveAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool AllMembers;
    public bool Conditional;
    public PreserveAttribute (bool allMembers, bool conditional)
    {
        AllMembers = allMembers;
        Conditional = conditional;
    }
    public PreserveAttribute ()
    {
    }
}
```

And then use that attribute on your JSON model/class:

```
[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
public class TestClass
{
  ~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `PreserveAttribute` at the top of your class

```
[PreserveAttribute(AllMembers = true)]
public class TestClass
{   
    public TestClass() {}

}
```

add one more class `PreserveAttribute` in class library

```
public sealed class PreserveAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public bool AllMembers;
    public bool Conditional;
}
```

**Edit**
Linking- Sdk & user assemblies

Skip linking assemblies- Newtonsoft.Json;

add `Newtonsoft.Json` in your Skip linking assemblies option

Comment: This is work with Xamarin forms but with Native ui its not work and I have taken separate class library for Android and iOS for Api call and Business logic.

Comment: Even I am using PCL with xamarin.android, the same attribute working for me. I got this error before few days,

Comment: In Same android project you can do this but if I have different class library for common logic, and in that common library i can't do it.

Comment: @ManishSharma -  Add one sealed class with name `PreserveAttribute` in your class library. I forgot to mention it before. If  still wont work try to follow my edit section.